# Excel: checking multiple vlookup instances for equality to a cell

Tags: vba, excel, indexing, vlookup

I have an excel formula that looks like this in psuedocode:

if
   vlookup = column name
then
   change value of cell to x
...

I need to make it something like:

if
   ANY INSTANCE OF vlookup = column name
then
   change value of cell to x

...
My code at the moment is :
=IF(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!$A$2:$K$362,5,FALSE)=$B$1,"x","")

How can I make it so that it compares multiple instances of vlookup to the string in B1 and not just the first instance? In other words, the A2 value repeats in the range but the value at each index 5 is different. I need to compare those all to the value of B1 independently.

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
=if(countifs(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$362, A2, Sheet1!$E$2:$E$362, B1), "x", text(,))
```

Comment: Beat me to it. except i had `""` instead :)

Comment: Yeah, I've been proselytizing the use of `text(,)` instead of `""` for a few weeks now (especially on [tag:excel-vba] questions).

Comment: @Jeeped - Any advantage to using `text(,)` over `""`?

Comment: You don't have to double-up double quotes within a quoted string when trying to apply a formula to a range in [tag:vba]. In the above, `"x"` will have to be changed to `""x""` but `text(,)` is left alone and not changed from `""` to `""""`.

Comment: Of course, `"x"` could be replaced with `char(120)` to avoid that double-up as well.